# QT's QWebView widget not accessible to screen readers

Tags: java, qt, accessibility, screen-readers, qt-jambi

I created this very simple QT Jambi application. It loads google. Based on the examples I found regarding QWebView, the program should run correctly.

```
package qtweb;

import com.trolltech.qt.core.QUrl;
import com.trolltech.qt.gui.QApplication;
import com.trolltech.qt.webkit.QWebView;

public class WebKit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QApplication.initialize(args);
        QWebView br = new QWebView();
        br.setWindowTitle("web test");
        br.setAccessibleDescription("test description");
        br.setAccessibleName("test name");
        br.load(new QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
        br.show();
        QApplication.execStatic();
    }

}
```

According to 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/accessible.html

> Either use standard widgets/controls which support ATs out of the box,
>   or make sure that your custom widgets and controls support
>   accessibility properly.

Since QT Jambi is just a java rapper to c++'s QT, I think this should also apply to QT Jambi. Unfortunately, when I ran my project, my screen readers (JAWS and NVDA) does not read anything aside from the title and AccesibleName. How can I make the contents of QWebView accessible to screen readers?

Comment: Screenreaders will be working with the HTML in the browser. Can you post what QT Jambi is generating so we can see the end result?

Comment: @stringy what do you mean by "generate"?